# Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу С#

Tags: c#

я делаю файловый менеджер на c#. У меня возникла проблема(картинка прилагается). 
Такое возникает когда я создаю файл и потом пытаюсь его переместить или скопировать, уже ранее созданные файлы нормально перемещаются и копируются.

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Создание файла : https://yadi.sk/i/8j1sUU8s3HXdVz

Comment: Приведите в вопросе текстовый вариант кода с проблемой. Скриншот крайне неудобен.

Comment: Приведите код (только пожалуйста текстом), где вы создаете файл, скорее всего забыли освободить какой-нибудь ресурс этого файла, в итоге ваша программа мешает сама себе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе с файлами, надо помнить, что если вы открыли файл монопольно, то пока не закроете поток связанный с этим файлом, попытки привязать к тому же файлу другой поток будут завершаться исключением. Корректно работу с файлом на чтение и запись можно сделать двумя способами:

Без освобождения потока:

```
Stream myStream;

using (myStream = File.Open(@"\test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(myStream);
    myWriter.WriteLine("test");
    //перед чтением необходимо вернуть указатель потока в нужное место, у меня - в начало файла.
    myStream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(myStream);
    Console.Write(myReader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

При таком подходе важно указать `FileAccess.ReadWrite` при создании потока и не закрывать `StreamWriter` и `StreamReader`, т.к. они при закрытии закрывают и поток. На все время работы файл будет заблокирован для других приложений.

С освобождением потока:

```
Stream myStream;

using (myStream = File.Open(@"\test.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write))
{
    StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(myStream);
    myWriter.WriteLine("test");
}

using (myStream = File.Open(@"\test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
{
    StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(myStream);
    Console.Write(myReader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

В этом случае после чтения и записи поток освобождается. Соответственно между чтением и записью (в любом порядке) файл доступен другим процессам.

Блоки `using` гарантируют освобождение потока. Вместо этого можно использовать `myStream.Close()`, но про это можно случайно забыть, так что `using` надежнее.

В принципе, отдельно поток можно и не создавать, `StreamWriter` и `StreamReader` сами умеют создавать поток к файлу по его имени, в таком случае код короче:

```
using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(@"\test.txt"))
{
    myWriter.WriteLine("test");
}

using (StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(@"\test.txt"))
{
    Console.Write(myReader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Но вы лишаетесь возможности настроить FileShare, и запретить другим программам блокировать файл пока вы им не пользуетесь.

Кроме всего перечисленного крайне желательно прежде чем открывать потоки чтения-записи, проверять существование файла, наличие необходимых прав доступа и т.д. потому что отсутствие какой либо из проверок в большинстве случаев гарантирует исключение.

Comment: +1, но проверка наличия файла — это не самый хороший совет: файл _может исчезнуть после проверки_. Поэтому ловить исключения всё равно необходимо. По теме: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: Надо использовать [конструктор, принимающий bool,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg712853(v=vs.110).aspx) чтобы поток не закрывался. Или хотя бы вызывать Flush если решили не закрывать StreamWriter.

Answer (score 0):

"я создаю файл и потом пытаюсь его переместить" - не закрыли созданный файл:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.create(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using (FileStream fs = newFile.Create()) 
{
}
```